# Creating and Using DLLs with C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, dll

Is there some sort of article or tutorial for creating and using DLLs in Visual Studio? I Googled and all I found was either about C# or C++. I'm not sure whether the DLL usage of C++ and C differs.

I found this article hosted at MSDN: [Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Dynamic Link Library (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
And, nearly nothing more about this. I prefer an article using Visual Studio 2010 if possible, and I'm using C.

Comment: So, that MSDN article is enough, you say? What about header files? Visual Studio 2010 does not create header files and stuff when I choose New DLL dialog. These are not problem, right? I can use header files or not, depending on my needs.

Comment: What you ask isn't clear if you know Windows. There are roughly two types of DLLs, one is Win32 DLL, another is .NET managed DLL, and they are used differently.

Comment: Just create the needed headers manually.

Comment: (Of course I'm talking about the normal win32 ones... that managed stuff is a piece of crap.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Thank you very much for your fast response.

Comment: @AlvinWong I'll use Win32 DLLs I guess. I don't want to mess with .NET. Any articles and readings for this? Thank you very much.

Comment: More to the link you already found on MSDN: [Windows Development Reference - Dynamic-Link Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This should be a good reading to get a notion of DLL role and function.

Comment: Visual Studio application wizard allows to check "Exports symbols" for Win32 Dll. When checked, example project with exported class and function is created. Just read this project, this should be enough to understand.